# Suggestions - showing file upload progress to user?

Tags: android

Does anyone have a recommendation on how to visually show progress of uploading a large file to a web server? My app needs to upload one photo at a time, as directed by the user. Images are about 200kb.

I don't want to put up a progress dialog and block the user from further interaction while the upload is in progress. Looks like I can:

1. Have a service upload the photo, and post status updates to the notification bar.
2. Upload through service (or bg thread), but post status updates to some in-app notification indicator.

I'm wondering if #1 is more standard, I like the idea of putting off updates to the notifcation bar so it's separated from my main app. I don't really want to build some global upload widget that has to be displayed on each activity my user navigates to.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a custumized notification with an embedded progress bar.

As described in this document:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView